# Thread hangs while executing DNS query employing JNDI library

Tags: java, multithreading, dns, java-7, jdk1.7

Below is the deadlock encountered as a result of thread getting locked while fetching TXT record from DNS

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:202)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.ensureBufferValid(NativePRNG.java:264)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:278)
    - locked <0x00000004f3cd17b0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$200(NativePRNG.java:125)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:114)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:466)
    - locked <0x00000004f111d290> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:488)
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:303)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:175)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:430)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:231)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:139)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:142)
```

On analysing, I find that this thread lock is due to the slowness in executing java.security.SecureRandom.next .

Below is jdk bug filed for a similar deadlock encountered
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066209

Can someone please let me know the reason for this occurring & how to get this resolved ?

Comment: Interesting. I'm seeing this too, but don't have a solution or a cause. I can tell you that in my case this has nothing to do with DNS but rather me using SecureRandom directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was seeing the same issue and I believe I've solved it. The problem appears to be that `SecureRandom.nextBytes` reads `/dev/random`. However, if there isn't sufficent entropy left in the `/dev/random` entropy pool that read will block. For possible solutions see [the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html) about the issue, [this excellent article](https://tersesystems.com/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/) about options for SecureRandom, and [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6202721) about setting the Java option to use `/dev/./urandom` rather than the seemingly equivalent `/dev/urandom`